# How to render dictionary new entry as new row of table in django?

Tags: python, django, file-upload, django-templates

I am having a difficulty implementing something that seemed quite straightforward in the beginning. More specifically, I want to upload a file in a folder and rename it. After renaming it I want to display a row in a table, which contains 3 columns. First column should display the old name of the file, second column should display the new name of the file and then third column should display a download button. I want the table to display this for every file that I upload (for instance if I have uploaded 5 files I wanna see 5 rows in the table) This is my `upload_file` view:

```
def upload_file(request):
  filedict = {}
    oldname = ""
    newname = ""
    if request.method == 'POST':
        uploaded_file = request.FILES['document']
        fs=FileSystemStorage()
        oldname = fs.save(uploaded_file.name,uploaded_file)
        newname = "new"+oldname
    global counter
    filedict['counter'] = { 'oldname': oldname, 'newname' : newname }
    counter+=1
    return render(request, 'files/renamefiles.html',{'names': 
   filedict})
```

and this is the table in my template `renamefiles.html`:

```
<div class="mt-5">
<table class="table table-hover">
 <thead>
    <tr>
        <th scope="col">Source File</th>
        <th scope="col">Renamed File</th>
        <th scope="col">Action</th>
    </tr>
 </thead>
  <tbody>
      <tr>
        {% for key, entry in dictionary.items %}
           {% for key2, data in entry.items %}
            <th id="filedata">{{data}}</th>
           {% endfor%}
        {% endfor%}
        <th><a class="btn btn-sm btncolor">Download File</a></th>
      </tr>
  </tbody>
 </table>
</div>
```

Despite that, when I load the page I see the download button on the first column (column `Source File`) and when I upload the file nothing is rendered. Does anyone have an idea as to how I could go about solving this? I appreciate any help you can provide

Comment: You add the dictionary with the name `names` into the render context but in the template you iterate over `dictionary.items`. You should iterate over `names.items`.

Comment: Use a model to store the file's metadata (filesystem path, old name, new name). That's the only sane solution here. Also do NOT use globals in Django - they are garanteed to break in very interesting ways on production and will provide you with days of fun trying to debug something you cannot even reproduce on your local dev environment...

Answer (score 0):

You need an additional Model and entries in a database for each uploaded file. That way, you will also have entries in the table even after the server has been restarted (the dictionary is only in the RAM).

Create a model like this:

```
class UploadedFile(Model):
    file = FileField(...)
    orig_filename = CharField(max_length=500)
```

You can then use a ModelForm in your view, or create the model object without changing much of your existing code.

Instead of using the dictionary for rendering the table, you would use a regular ListView based on that model.

This part of the documentation should get you started:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/file-uploads/#handling-uploaded-files-with-a-model